# audioSessionGetProperty doesn't work (iOS)

Tags: volume, audiosession

I am trying to detect the current volume, but the result is always 0.  this is my codes:

in the view controller.m

1. import the AudioToolbox.
2. in viewDidLoad method, 
     AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
3. in viewDidLoad method, following the above initialization method.

   ```
     Float32 volume_reading;
   ```

   UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(Float32);

   AudioSessionGetProperty (
                            kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume,
                            &dataSize,
                            &volume_reading
                            );
4. po volume_reading in the debugger, result is 0.

Any suggestion?  Thanks very much.

Comment: A correction in my above post. The item 1 should be import #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat older question, but did you initialize the audio session?

Example:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, (__bridge void*)self);
```